# generate multiple documents

Tags: multiple-files

Is it possible to generate multiple documents files from one .tex file? For instance:

```
\begin{document}
\input{part1}
\input{part2}
\end{document}
```

I would like part1 to be generated in part1.pdf and part2 to be generated in part2.pdf.

Comment: There's also a question about creating chapter PDFs